# Angular4 HttpClient don't send my cookies

Tags: angular, httpclient

i use HttpClient for a CORS post request from "example.fr" to "api.example.fr".

I receive the correct value from my REST API Server :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://example.fr
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
```

But I need to send my Cookies to api.example but that doesn't work.

I am calling post method like:

```typescript
return this.http.post(Config.ROUTES.auth.register, user, { withCredentials: true, })
      .catch(Utils.handleError);
```

Can someone help me please ?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: make sure your client and server are in the same domain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SachilaRanawaka. My API is in the same domain. I just use the subdomain api.example.fr.
The cookie can't be sent from a parent domain : example.fr to a subdomain api.example.fr ?

Comment: It depends on how the cookie was set. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain

Comment: Thanks a lot guys have change my Cookie domain to .example.fr and it works !! Thanks again :)